# Why does NSCollectionView.makeItem sometimes crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

For some reason, my app just started doing this after months of not doing so. This popped up after a seemingly-unrelated use of `OperationQueue` (I always use `main`, so it's done on Thread 1).

[image: Six attempts to call the same collectionView.makeItem function, the fourth failing with reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS]

As you can see, I call the exact same function 6 times in a row, and only on the 4th time does it fail. I see no pattern...

Comment: I'm sure more code might help, but I've no idea what else to post. Let me know what more you need to know and I'll do what I can.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done very extensive digging or testing, but it seems a block like this was the culprit:

```swift
collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
    collectionView.reloadItems()
}, completionHandler: { [weak self] _ in
    // cleanup
})
```

Seems the collection view doesn't like doing much more than insert+remove inside the batch update context. Changing it to this seems to have cured the crash:

```swift
collectionView.reloadItems()
// cleanup
```